# Auto Increment key based on another column via JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there any way to increment a key based on column rather than a row.
i.e.:

```
ColA , ColB, ColC
A   , 1    , text3
B   , 1    , text12
A   , 2    , any text55
A   , 3    , any text4
B   , 2    , any text55
```

When ColA contains same value then ColB value is incremented.
Is there any way to do it via JPA or Hibernate rather than doing query of Max ?

Comment: As this is a JPA question, posting  the relevant Entities might be useful.Is @OrderColumn of any use? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: When a record is inserted it's id should be incremented. as you can see ColB increment for ColA.

Comment: Then do you still think @OrderColumn will work? Is there any example?

Comment: Without the entities can't say.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to implement logic into the when you add a new item.

You can use @PrePersist annotatiom

Comment: This is not an aswer, should be a comment

Comment: Then don't answer because this way your answer will be deleted, and start earning reputation to be able to comment.

Comment: I appreciate his answer @haytem